# Using Object.assign() or spread ... operator in pug template

Tags: pug

I have a 2 Pug files.

The first define config object (base.pug) object like below

```
const config = { name: 'abc', age: 25}
```

The other Pug template (main.pug) which includes `base.pug` and wants to additional property to an object.

```
script.
  const base = {tech: 'js'}
  const mergedObject = {config, base} // I supposed this should merge 2 object.
  const mergedObjectWithSpreadOp = {...config, tech: 'js'} // again I supposed this should merge 2 object.
```

Note: pug-runtime used is 2.0.1

None of my approaches worked. How can I achieve this?

I want to merge object from `base.pug` with `main.pug`

Comment: Are you trying to render a `<script>` element client-side with that javascript written out? Or are you wanting to use a merged object server-side in Pug and don't care if it's output client-side?

Comment: Hello Sean, Thank you for replying. I am trying  to "render a <script> element client-side with that javascript written out".

Answer (score 0):

As you've discovered, writing something in Pug like this—

```
script.
  const foo = {...config, tech: 'js'}
```

—just renders that text as-is within a script tag. This is expected behavior for the [tag interpolation syntax](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html#tag-interpolation) you're using.

If you want to merge two objects in Pug, and then render the merged object as a string within a script tag, you'll need to do something like this:

```
script.
  const foo = !{JSON.stringify({...config, tech: 'js'})}
```

Where:

- `{...config, tech: 'js'}` uses the JS spread syntax to create a single new object
- `JSON.stringify(...)` converts that object into a string representing it
- `!{...}` is the Pug syntax for unescaped string interpolation

That last part is what tells Pug to evaluate that code instead of just rendering as text.